# Why is Object.ToString a virtual method?

Tags: c#, .net

If it wasn't a virtual method, you can still achieve the same effect by just writing your `ToString` method normally, right?

You could even use the optional `new` keyword.

Wouldn't this have better performance?

Comment: Why has this question been downvoted?

Comment: Not my downvote, but when anyone searches for ToString() or virtual methods then this question should not be near the top of the list

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> If it wasn't a virtual method, you can still achieve the same effect, by just writing your ToString method as normal, right?

No. Consider (e.g.) the signature of (one overload of) the `Console.WriteLine` function:

```
void Console.WriteLine(object o);
```

If `ToString` were novirtual, this would always call the `System.Object.ToString` implementation, not the one on the actual object passed to the function.

Comment: Thanks, if it was a generic method, then it would work, right?

Comment: No it wouldn't. Please consult a tutorial about polymorphism.

Comment: If it was void Console.WriteLine(T t), I think it would.

Comment: If it were a C++ template it would work. But with a C# or Java generic, the argument would have to implement an interface, which would involve dynamic dispatch much like a virtual method.

Comment: But it would require some constraints on T. Same problem just got more complicated.

Comment: Why not spend 30 seconds writing a console application?

Comment: I wrote a sample, but there are issues because I can't add my method to show up on T without additional complexity. But if there was a non virtual method there, I could try it out.

Comment: Yeah like if the Object actually had a GetString method that's non-virtual, then I could try it out. I tried using an extension method, it didn't work. The GetString doesn't show up on T, which requires interface constraints, etc to get this working. Then of course it would defeat the purpose.

Comment: To adapt a German saying: “If we had cheese, we could feast on cheese sandwiches – *if* we had bread”, right? ;-)

Comment: @Konrad: I hadn't heard that one. Another is, "If we had ham, we could have ham and cheese, if we had cheese".

Answer (score 4):

Along the lines of Konrad's comment:

```
public Class A
{
    public new string ToString()
    {
        return "Hello from A";
    }
}

object a = new A();
a.ToString();
```

Would NOT return 'Hello from A' but instead would return the type name (which is what object's implementation does).

Answer (score 4):

You could ask the same of any virtual method.

So this question is basically the same as asking "What is the purpose of virtual methods?"